# ModelState.IsValid == false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I am working on a log on page, and no matter what I do I cannot get my ModelState.IsValid to return true so that I can sign the user in. 
 I have this code in my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateLogon(LogonModel logon)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        StaffModel staff;
        if (staffAuthenticationService.ValidateLogon(logon.UserName, logon.Password, out staff, out logon))
        {
            staffAuthenticationService.SignIn(staff);
            return Json(new { success = true, redirect = "/Home/ModuleIndex", staff = staff });
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username and/or Password may be incorrect");
    }

    return Json(new { errors = GetErrorsFromModelState() });   
}
```

My Logon Model has a Staff model and a User model, my service method validateLogon is passed a logon model. I tried using:

```
var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));
```

and logging the errors, but I see no errors and valid is always false.

Is there a better way to validate a user than with this dictionary object, or a work around that I have not found. I have been looking for a couple of hours.

**Update:**

```
public class LogonModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    [DataType("UserModel")]
    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Staff")]
    [DataType("StaffModel")]
    public StaffModel Staff { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your username")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Terms Of Use Signed")]
    public bool IsTermsOfUseSigned { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Privacy Agreement Signed")]
    public bool IsPrivacyAgreementSigned { get; set; }

    [Display(Name= "System Message")]
    public string SystemLoginMessage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Version")]
    public string DatabaseVersion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Copyright Date")]
    public string CopyrightDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Web Server")]
    public string WebServer { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Value cannot exceed 50 characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Value cannot exceed 50 characters")]
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last 4 digits of XXXX SSN")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Value must be 4 numbers")]
    public string SsnSuffix { get; set; }

    public int LogonValidationStep { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I see in the debugger when I hover over the the if statement: IsValid = false
then when I step into the function it falls right to the error message.

Comment: Can you post your LogonModel class? Can you set a break point and see what error is in the modelstate that is returning false. You might see that a certain field is not being populated that might be required or something.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your Action and examine the `this.ModelState` property, specifically the Keys and Values. The Values might not necessarily contain an Exception.

Comment: To add to this, here's a helpful snippet to get all the errors:     var errorList = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

Comment: @Guyute If you are using `MVC 3` or above just use `SimpleMembrshipProvider` which in fact comes integrated with one of the premade templates for MVC. As for the `ModelState` we need to see the model that you pass to your `View` and also, you need to check the `logon` value when result is returned from the view and try to find what exactly breaks the model.

Comment: I set a break on line 131 of my controller and that is where I see my ModelState.IsValid is false when I hover over it and twirl down the arrow.

Comment: @Guyute In order to get `false` form `ModelState.IsValid` one or more of your `Required` fields should be populated with incorrect data. So make sure that : `LastName` is populated with some string no longer than 50 letters, `DateOfBirth` is populated and is actually a string and not a `DateTime` object, `SsnSuffix` is populated with string no longer than 50 letters. Make sure you do that and try again. In fact just temporary remove `Required` from `DateOfBirth` and submit the form leaving it blank and see if you pass the check.

Comment: @Leron that was it, thank you, I did not mean to include that required field in my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your check:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

returns false, that most probably means that one of the required fields in your model, used in the view is populated with incorrect result. After you post your model the `DateOfBirth` field seemed the most suspicious so removing the `Required` attribute made us able to find out what cause the problem and to solve the problem temporary.

From now on you have two options - just leave it as it is (I do not recommend that) or make further investigation why you are not getting the expected data for that field. In other words, don't avoid the problems, but try to solve them and learn from them.

If my post helped you you may as well accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my long term solution is to create another model that will be used for the password recovery process. We have staff users and non staff users and they both recover their passwords using the same work flow, so having a generic model will come in handy when I get there. I was trying to cram all log on cases into one model, view and control. and hide and display views as conditions are met or not met. Sometimes I guess you cant get everything in one fell swoop. I am still a new programmer so I tend to over think things sometimes.

Comment: @Guyute As I wrote in my comment in your original post, it's really worth it using the integrated `MVC` tools for membership like `SimpleMembershipProvider`, `Identity` or something else that you may found more suitable. They are pretty extendable and offer a lot of the things that you'll have to do out of the box. And not at least, the learning curve is not that big so it's worth it since, this is one of the most common tasks for each developer/application.